# How to create a new command with formatted string?

Tags: luatex

When I try to create a new command that contains a formatted string, I get an error:

```
\directlua]:1: unfinished string near <eof>.
```

Please, help me fix my error. This is code from my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\formula[4]{
\luaexec{
tex.print("test")
for a=#1,#2 do
for b=#1,#2 do
tex.print(string.format("\luatexluaescapestring{#3}".."(%s+%s)^2=%s^2+2*%s*%s+%s^2=%s".."\luatexluaescapestring{#4}",a,b,a,a,b,b,(a+b)^2))
end
end
}}
\begin{document}
\formula{-5}{5}{\[}{\]}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\luaexec` tries to change the catcodes, such that you can use `%` literally in it's argument, but this does not work inside a macro: When the macro is defined, `\luaexec` is only saved and not executed, so the catcodes do not change yet. So the `%` in the lua string starts a TeX comment and the remaining line is discarded long before the macro is ever executed.

Tl;dr: Do not use `\luaexec` inside a macro.

Instead, you can move all the Lua stuff into a function and only call the function from the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode*}
  function myfunc(start, finish, prefix, suffix)
    tex.print("test")
    for a=start,finish do
      for b=start,finish do
        tex.print(string.format("%s(%s+%s)^2=%s^2+2*%s*%s+%s^2=%s%s",prefix,a,b,a,a,b,b,(a+b)^2,suffix))
      end
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\formula[4]{\directlua{myfunc(#1,#2,"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#3}}","\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#4}}")}}
\begin{document}
\formula{-5}{5}{\[}{\]}
\end{document}
```

Additonally, I would always prefer the `token` scanning functions instead of using arguments as literal Lua expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode*}
  function myfunc(start, finish, prefix, suffix)
    tex.print("test")
    for a=start,finish do
      for b=start,finish do
        tex.print(string.format("%s(%i+%i)^2=%i^2+2*%i*%i+%i^2=%i%s",prefix,a,b,a,a,b,b,(a+b)^2,suffix))
      end
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\formula[4]{%
  \directlua{myfunc(token.scan_int(), token.scan_int(),token.scan_string(),token.scan_string())}
    \numexpr#1\relax
    \numexpr#2\relax
    {\unexpanded{#3}}
    {\unexpanded{#4}}}
\begin{document}
\formula{-5}{5}{\[}{\]}
\end{document}
```

This improves the integration into the TeX ecosystem because it allows to use the same arithmetic expressions as in other TeX commands instead of using the Lua rules. For examples TeX counters can be used asinstead of number literals.

Comment: Thank you for your help very mutch. Now it works for me,but i want understand two commands. Can you please explain me,why we must use environment luacode with * and what means commands \luaescapestring and \unexpanded? Thanks everybody for explanation,because i very new in lualatex,so i want inprove my skils in lualatex.

Comment: `\luaescapestring` is just `\luatexluaescapestring`, in recent LaTeX version you no longer need the `luatex` prefix. `\unexpanded` avoids expansion: You want `\[` and `\]` to be copied without change to Lua, so you have to use `\unexpanded` to stop TeX from replacing the macro with it's definition.